# Winform:client maintenance mode?

Tags: c#, winforms, n-tier-architecture

In asp.net, there is app_offline.htm which let you shutdown website gracefully.I want to implemet similar function in client.
There is a flag to set to maintenance mode,if flag is on:

- When user start the client, user will be prompted something like "system is under maintenance, try again after 30 mins".
- Any new update/delete/add operations, similar message prompted.
- Ongoing requests will be processed.

How to implement this?

Comment: do you have an ntier application?

Comment: @DanielA.White Yes, It is

Comment: what things have you tried to implement it?

Comment: Use MessageBox.Show() in the Main() method.  The conditions that trigger this are of course entirely up to you to decide.  Using File.Exist() to check if a file named "app_offline.htm" exists in a specific directory will work just fine, assuming nobody forgets to remove it again ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the differences in application architecture, this is not something that is going to have a "one-size-fits-all" type solution that is going to work for everyone.

app_offline.html for web applications is truly a "sledgehammer" approach.  The app is down, yes it is graceful but it is a 100% hard stop.

A primitive way of doing this within your application could be to have a service call that you make on a regular basis for "Is online" or similar.  If it returns false, force quit your current form and show a splashpage.

But this is really going to depend on architecture.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a condition when starting the client, but you if you want the same behavior like **app_offline.htm**, you may also want to put under maintenance **an already opened client**.

In this case, you can install a [MessageFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.addmessagefilter.aspx) in order to  intercept any event across the whole Winforms app.